# Scilab champ to plot vector field gives different results

Tags: plot, graph, scilab

Hy friends

This is the problem :

I write  this code to plot e vector the vector field (-xi+jy):

```
x=-2:1:2;
y=-2:1:2;
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);
champ(x,y,-X,Y)
```

It should be plotted e clockwise rotational vector field; but a counterclokwise one is plotted; to have the right result I must write

```
champ(x,y,X,-Y);
```

As other example if i plot the field (xi +yj) which is e single positive charge field :

```
champ(x,y,X,Y)
```

the right plot should be this :

[link to image (xi+yj)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/si9Ep.png)

but this wrong one is plotted

[link to image wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idaal.png)

to plot the right one I must write :

```
champ(x,y,X',Y');
```

Can anybody explain me the correct way to use the champ function to plot vector field? Or must I every time verify with another program if the parameters are  corrected inserted?

Thanks for any help.

(All the functions are tested with various online vetctor field editors)

Answer (score 0):

First, (-X,Y) is **not** a clockwise field, as proved by the following Wolfram alpha plot:

[image]

A simple clockwise field is (Y,-X) and you can have a correct representation in Scilab by using `ndgrid` instead of `meshgrid`:

```
x=-2:1:2;
y=-2:1:2;
[X,Y]=ndgrid(x,y);
champ(x,y,Y,-X)
```

[image]

`meshgrid` is ok for surfaces plot. For 2D plots use `ndgrid`.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that this is due to the coordinate system. The Y axis is inverted (upside down). It starts at the upper left corner.

Comment: Don't give answers if you don't know how Scilab works.